# Como puedo descargar mi compilado de un proyecto desde código

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero poder descargar de manera local mi aplicación web, la aplicación esta desarrollada en c# .net y de que manera puedo descargar toda aplicación web para que pueda verse de manera local.

Comment: No entiendo, lo que puedes descargar es el html que visualizas en el browser, si quieres descargar el codigo no podras, eso esta en el servidor

Comment: Bueno para que el usuario lo pueda visualizar cuando se quede sin Internet, cuando no este conectado en el servidor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si quieres capacidad `offline` en un desarrollo web puede aplicar la que proporciona `html 5` usando:

[Let’s Take This Offline](https://diveinto.html5doctor.com/offline.html)

[Build an HTML5 Offline Application with Application Cache, Web Storage and ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codemag.com/article/1112051/Build-an-HTML5-Offline-Application-with-Application-Cache-Web-Storage-and-ASP.NET-MVC)

Para el html puedes definir `cache manifest`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="/cache.appcache">
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

Y para los datos el `Web Storage` en donde detectas la conexion y puedes en ese periodo `offline` guardar los datos en el `localStorage`

Comment: porque un voto negativo? al menos de una razon para poder mejorar una respuesta que fue marcada como correcta. Votar negativo solo por hacerlo no ayuda en nada

Answer (score 0):

Me he visto en una situación similar, y he investigado y creo que la mejor solución es convertir la app mvc a [PWA](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.xataka.com/basics/que-es-una-aplicacion-web-progresiva-o-pwa/amp)(Progressive Web App) esto utiliza un [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=es) que se encarga de servir todas las peticiones ajax. Y podemos aprovechar esto para mantenerlas disponibles offline y al recuperar la conexión sincronizar con el servidor.

Esto claro lleva de modificaciones según la aplicación. Pero se basa en usar el [Cache Storage](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa?hl=es) en combinación del [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=es).

Este ejemplo me guío para implementar una app asp.net mvc 5 a [PWA](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.xataka.com/basics/que-es-una-aplicacion-web-progresiva-o-pwa/amp).

Esta en ingles: [Implementar PWA MVC 5](http://www.spheregen.com/implementing-pwa-behavior-to-asp-net-mvc-5-apps/)

A mi humilde opinión es la solución mas avanzada usted decidirá si vale la pena el desarrollo de esta lógica para su aplicación.